# Changing SharedPreferences from onTaskRemoved in a service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-sharedpreferences

I need to change a sharedpreference from a service when my app is closed. This is basically to check if app is force-closed (swiped from recent app list), while the service was running. However, the shared prefernce does not seem to be going through? Might this be because SharedPreferences is unavailable once the activities/components have been closed and service is the last thing to close from the app?

Here is the snippet from onTask:

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = (SharedPreferences) getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SkiCompanionPreferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("recording", false).commit();


        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
```

Comment: try replacing `commit()` with `apply()`

Comment: I already did that - didn't work :/

Comment: @ShaneMonksO'Byrne make sure there is no typo in name of SharedPreferences

Comment: A typo wouldn't have made `sharedPreferences.edit();`to crash with NPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you write **android:stopWithTask="false"** for Service in Manifest?

Comment: Interesting solution to the problem: when you have android:stopWithTask="true" in the manifest, onTaskRemoved is never called. To fix this, I changed to android:stopWithTask="false" and after changing Shared preferences in onTaskRemoved(), I also added the line stopSelf(). Thanks Eldor